# What is the difference between git branch and git checkout -b?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm very new to git/gitlab and want to confirm the difference between the 2 commands in the first screen shot. What is the purpose of having 2 commands which both create new branches. Why is 'git branch' even needed?

Is it purely there in case i want to create a new branch but not switch to that branch? So i very minor time save instead of doing 'git checkout -b new_branch' and then 'git checkout previous_branch'.

Also why does it say to reference the current HEAD? I assume this is related to the 'remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master' in the second screen shot?

I tried 'git branch test_branch_name' which created the new branch without needed to reference the current HEAD, so why does it mention referencing the current HEAD?

[image]

[image]

Probably not necessary, but here's a link for where the first screen shot comes from:
https://about.gitlab.com/images/press/git-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: How is the title related to the content of your question? Why is this tagged r and rstudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git checkout -b [name]` is short for `git branch [name] && git checkout [name]`. The recent versions of Git also support `git switch` to checkout a branch.

`git branch [name]` is equivalent to `git branch [name] HEAD`. `git branch [name]` is a special case of `git branch [name] [start-point]`. When `start-point` is omitted, it defaults to `HEAD`.

For more details, see [git branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).

Answer (score 2):

To fill in a few more details:

> ... Why is 'git branch' even needed?

The `git branch` command has many options, such as:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to
```

or:

```
git branch --list
```

or:

```
git branch -d
```

which do things that neither `git checkout` nor the new (Git 2.23 or later) `git switch` will do.

The things that `git branch --list` does *can* be done with `git for-each-ref`.  The thing that `git branch --set-upstream-to` does *can* be done with `git config`.  If you'd like an analogy, Git commands are *tools*.  You can cut wood with a bandsaw, a hacksaw, a coping saw, a drill, or a chisel.  If you'd like to make dovetails, most of these tools *could* do the job—but it will go a lot faster and better and easier with a router and a dovetailing jig.  If your goal is to put in a lock and doorknob set, consider a hole saw and the drill.

(The `git checkout` command actually has *too many* tools built into it—in my opinion anyway.  Apparently, finally, the official Git maintenance folks are coming around to this same opinion, as two of the main jobs that `git checkout` can perform are now provided by two separate front-end commands: `git switch` and `git restore`.  Of course, in typical Git fashion, `git restore` can now do a few things that `git checkout` can't.)

Git is in some ways mainly a graph-manipulating suite of tools that happen to drag source code along with them.  The graph you manipulate is the *commit graph*, which is made up of nodes (graph vertices) that are commits, connected by one-way edge links (arcs) that are the parent hash IDs stored in each commit-node.  See [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).